# Is it safe to use this in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, threadpool

I am reading open source code of [thread_pool](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h)

In its constructor it shows

```
// the constructor just launches some amount of workers
inline ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t threads)
    :   stop(false)
{
    for(size_t i = 0;i<threads;++i)
        workers.emplace_back(
            [this]
            {
                for(;;)
                {
                    std::function<void()> task;

                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
                        this->condition.wait(lock,
                            [this]{ return this->stop || !this->tasks.empty(); });
                        if(this->stop && this->tasks.empty())
                            return;
                        task = std::move(this->tasks.front());
                        this->tasks.pop();
                    }

                    task();
                }
            }
        );
}
```

My wonder is that is `this` safe-used when `workers.emplace_back`?Though it is used to construct another thread, but is it possible when constructing threads in `workers`(i.e. `this` is used in other threads), `ThreadPool` is not fully constructed and `this` is not fully valid?

Comment: You *can* assign values to non-static class data members inside a constructor body. This fact alone means that `this` has to be valid.

Comment: By the opening curly-brace of the constructor-body, all member-variables of the object are already fully constructed, so there's no harm in using `this` in the constructor.

Comment: One thing to beware of, probably not relevant here, is that if you were to subclass `ThreadPool`, your subclass is not fully initialized at this time. So, if these workers rely on any behavior or data that requires a fully-initialized subclass (for instance, if there are virtual methods that you override) then it can be a problem.